# Determing for particle density of many particle species in plasma

Tags: plasma-physics, fusion

For quasi-neutrality plasma of many species, the relation of electron density and ion density said that

\begin{equation}
n_{\text{e}} = \sum_{s}Z_{\text{i},s}n_{\text{i},s},
\end{equation}
where $n_{\text{e}}$, $Z_{\text{i},s}$, and $n_{\text{i},s}$ are electron density, charge state of $s$th ion species and ion density of $s$th ion specie. In mixture plasma containing with electrons, proton and oxygen ion (C$^{4+}$), is it true that electron density about $5\times 10^{15}$ m$^{-3}$, thus proton density will be $1\times 10^{15}$ m$^{-3}$ and C$^{4+}$ density be $4\times 10^{15}$ m$^{-3}$?

Comment: $10^{18}$ m$^{-3}$ for protons ? I think $C^{4+}$ should have the same density that the density of protons.

Comment: @M06-2x Sorry about wrong typing. I've adjusted the numver of proton density to be $1\times 10 ^{5} $ already

Comment: If you use your expression, the charge density of C$^{4+}$ will be $1.6 \times 10^6$

Comment: It doesn't have to be anything, you only know that $n_{e} = n_{p} + 4 n_{C}$.  Usually it is the case that $n_{p} \gg n_{C}$ in most space plasmas, but this is not necessarily so in a lab plasma depending on the target/plasma source.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Is it possible if I set particle density ratio of electron : proton : carbon (+4) ion to be 1 : $\frac{1}{2}$ : $4\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)$ for the implest case of quasi-neutral plasma in experiment?

Comment: As I said, $n_{p}$ and $n_{C}$ can be anything so long as they add up as shown above to the total electron density. There is no "right" answer given the lack of constraints in your question.